# Windows Azure staging <--> production causing conflicts & errors on table storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles, azure-queues

We had a terrible problem/experience yesterday when trying to swap our staging <--> production role.

**Here is our setup:**

We have a workerrole picking up messages from the queue. These messages are processed on the role. (Table Storage inserts, db selects etc ). This can take maybe 1-3 seconds per queue message depending on how many table storage posts he needs to make. He will delete the message when everything is finished.

**Problem when swapping:**

When our staging project went online our production workerrole started erroring.

When the role wanted to process queue messsage it gave a constant stream of '**EntityAlreadyExists**' errors. Because of these errors queue messages weren't getting deleted. This caused the queue messages to be put back in the queue and back to processing and so on....

When looking inside these queue messages and analysing what would happend with them we saw they were actually processed but not deleted.

The problem wasn't over when deleting these faulty messages. Newly queue messages weren't processed as well while these weren't processed yet and no table storage records were added, which sounds very strange.

When deleting both staging and producting and publishing to production again everything started to work just fine.

**Possible problem(s)?**

We have litle 2 no idea what happened actually.

- Maybe both the roles picked up the same messages and one did the post and one errored?
- ...???

**Possible solution(s)?**

We have some idea's on how to solve this 'problem'.

- Make a poison message fail over system? When the dequeue count gets over X we should just delete that queue message or place it into a separate 'poisonqueue'.
- Catch the EntityAlreadyExists error and just delete that queue message or put it in a separate queue.
- ...????

**Multiple roles**

I suppose we will have the same problem when putting up multiple roles?

Many thanks.

**EDIT 24/02/2012 - Extra information**

- We actually use the **GetMessage()**
- Every item in the queue is unique and will generate unique messages in table Storage. Little more information about the process: A user posts something and will have to be distributed to certain other users. The message generate from that user will have a unique Id (guid). This message will be posted into the queue and picked up by the worker role. The message is distributed over several other tables (partitionkey -> UserId, rowkey -> Some timestamp in ticks & the unique message id. So there is almost no chance the same messages will be posted in a normal situation.
- The invisibility time out **COULD be a logical explanation** because some messages could be distributed to like 10-20 tables. This means 10-20 insert without the batch option. Can you set or expand this **invisibility time** out?
- Not deleting the queue message because of an exception **COULD** be a explanation as well because we didn't implement any poison message fail over YET ;).

Comment: The latest queue implementation does allow you to change the visibility timeout.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh452234.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly have a fault on handling double messages. The fact that your ID is unique doesn't mean that the message will not be processed twice in some occasions like:

1. The role dying and with partially finished work, so the message will re-appear for processing in the queue
2. The role crashing unexpected, so the message ends up back in the queue
3. The FC migrating moving your role and you don't have code to handle this situation, so the message ends up back in the queue

In all cases, you need code that handles the fact that the message will re-appear. One way is to use the [DequeueCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudqueuemessage.dequeuecount.aspx) property and check how many times the message was removed from a Queue and received for processing. Make sure you have code that handles partial processing of a message.

Now what probably happened during swapping was, when the production environment became the staging and staging became production, both of them were trying to receive the same messages so they were basically competing each other fro those messages, which is probably not bad because this is a known pattern to work anyway but when you killed your old production (staging) every message that was received for processing and wasn't finished, ended up back in the Queue and your new production environment picked the message for processing again. Having no code logic to handle this scenario and a message was that partially processed, some records in the tables existed and it started causing the behavior you noticed.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the Staging vs. Production issue, having a mechanism that handles poison messages is critical.  We've implemented an abstraction layer over Azure queues that automatically moves messages over to a poison queue once they've been attempted to be processed some configurable amount of times.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible causes:

How are you reading the queue messages?  If you are doing a Peek Message then the message will still be visible to be picked up by another role instance (or your staging environment) before the message is deleted.  You want to make sure you are using Get Message so the message is invisible until it can be deleted.

Is it possible that your first role crashed after doing the work for the message but prior to deleting the message?  This would cause the message to become visible again and get picked up by another role instance.  At that point the message will be a poison message which will cause your instances to constantly crash.

This problem almost certainly has nothing to do with Staging vs Production, but is most likely caused by having multiple instances reading from the same queue.  You can probably reproduce the same problem by specifying 2 instances, or by deploying the same code to 2 different production services, or by running the code locally on your dev machine (still pointing to Azure storage) using 2 instances.

In general you do need to handle poison messages so you need to implement that logic anyways, but I would suggest getting to the root cause of this problem first, otherwise you are just going to run into a lot more problems later on.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I have edited my post with more information :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your worker role is actually doing I'm taking a guess here, but it sounds like when you have two instances of your worker role running you are getting conflicts while trying to write to an Azure table.  It is likely to be because you have code that looks something like this:

```cs
var queueMessage = GetNextMessageFromQueue();    

Foo myFoo = GetFooFromTableStorage(queueMessage.FooId);

if (myFoo == null)
{
    myFoo = new Foo {
                        PartitionKey = queueMessage.FooId
                    };

    AddFooToTableStorage(myFoo);
}

DeleteMessageFromQueue(queueMessage);
```

If you have two adjacent messages in the queue with the same `FooId` it is quite likely that you'll end up with both of the instances checking to see if the `Foo` exists, not finding it then trying to create it.  Whichever instance is the last to try and save the item will get the "Entity already exists" error.  Because it errored it never gets to the delete message part of the code and therefore it becomes visible back on the queue after a period of time.

As others have said, dealing with poison messages is a really good idea.

**Update 27/02**
If it's not subsequent messages (which based on your partition/row key scheme I would say it's unlikely), then my next bet would be it's the same message appearing back in the queue after the visibility timeout.  By default if you're using [.GetMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758456.aspx) the timeout is 30 seconds.  It has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758358.aspx) which allows you to specify how long that time frame is.  There is also the [.UpdateMessage() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudqueue.updatemessage.aspx) that allows you to update that timeout as you're processing the message.  For example you could set the initial visibility to 1 minute, then if you're still processing the message 50 seconds later, extent it for another minute.

Comment: The messages are 100% unique :) I have updated my post with a bit more information.

Answer (score 1):

With  queues you need to code with idempotency in mind and expect and handle the ‘EntityAlreadyExists’ as a viable response.

As others have suggested, causes could be

- Multiple message in the queue with the same identifier.
- Are peeking for the message and not reading it form the queue and so not making them invisible.
- Not deleting the message because an exception was thrown before you can delete them.
- Taking too long to process the message so it cannot be deleted (because invisibility was timed out) and appears again

Without looking at the code I am guessing that it is either the 3 or 4 option that is occurring.

If you cannot detect the issue with a code review, you may consider adding time based logging and try/catch wrappers to get a better understanding.

Using queues effectively, in a multi-role environment, requires a slightly different mindset and running into such issues early is actually a blessing in disguise.

**Appended 2/24**

Just to clarify, modifying the invisibility time out is not a generic solution to this type of problem. Also, note that this feature although available on the REST API, may not be available on the queue client.

Other options involve writing to table storage in an asynchronous manner to speed up your processing time, but again this is a stop gap measures which does not really address the underlying paradigm of working with queues.

So, the bottom line is to be idempotent. You can try using the table storage upsert (update or insert) feature to avoid getting the ‘EntitiyAlreadyExists’ error, if that works for your code. If all you are doing is inserting new entities to azure table storage then the upsert should solve your problem with minimal code change.

If you are doing updates then it is a different ball game all together. One pattern is to pair updates with dummy inserts in the same table with the same partition key so as to error out if the update occurred previously and so skip the update. Later after the message is deleted, you can delete the dummy inserts. However, all this adds to the complexity, so it is much better to revisit the architecture of the product; for example, do you really need to insert/update into so many tables?

Comment: Your 3 and 4 option 'look' right indeed. I have posted a bit more information.